# Incompatibility of packages ucs, CJKutf8, siunitx

Tags: siunitx, cjk

I am using pdftex to write a book that mixes mathematics, Chinese and transliterated Arabic. The following setup

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\inputencoding{utf8x}
Muḥammad
\inputencoding{utf8}

\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gkai}
张仪
\end{CJK*}
\end{document}
```

works fine with TeXLive 2017, but it give a weird error under TeXLive 2018 and 2019:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.dfu
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.dfu:115: Missing numbe
r, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   F
l.115 ...icodeCharacter{FEFF}{\ifhmode\nobreak\fi}

?
```

Unfortunately such characters as Ḫ and ḥ force me to  use utf8x.

I can still manage with TeXLive 2017, but perhaps the unicode experts can track down the problem.

Comment: A very warm welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: You probably know this, but: if you can switch from PDFLaTeX to LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you can use Unicode and system fonts natively.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use ucs/utf8x, you can add the missing declarations yourself. Depending on the number of declarations it can mean a bit work, but at the end you will have something that is not incompatible with standard latex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{1E25}{\d{h}}
\begin{document}

Muḥammad

\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gkai}
张仪
\end{CJK*}
\end{document}
```

[image]